# Eclipse shows "Cannot execute binary file" when running Java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a simple Java application but when I run it on Eclipse, the following error will be shown in console.

```
/Eter/Jack/Java - Installation/jre1.7.0/bin/java: /Eter/Jack/Java - Installation/jre1.7.0/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

Running this command "java -version" in terminal shows following

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should reinstall Java, it looks like you've given a bad path... or you're trying to run a version of Java for a different platform.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I re-installed Java to no luck,

Comment: Based on your error above, it's the wrong Java. What platform, and what did you download?

Comment: I installed "jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg" on my mac

Comment: **jre1.7.0** is not **8u25**.

Comment: I removed jre1.7.0, it is not showing Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the jre1.7.0 to find out it has .exe files. I removed the folder and it showed a new error as following.

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) I changed the version of my Java on Eclipse and that solved the problem.